# ESLint Vue plugin showing false positives for vue/comment-directive

Tags: eslint, vuejs3, vite

After migrating from VueCLI to Vite, I have to do the linting "manually" as far as I understand; correct me if I'm wrong.
As I only want to lint my .ts and .html files (I separate them even for components), I have this script in my package json:

`"lint": "eslint --ext .ts --ext .html src/"`

It found some issues like missing `:key` in loops, but it also shows me this error for each template:

> error  clear  vue/comment-directive

And this is always the closing tag of any root elements within my template.html
If there is only one root element I get one warning for the file, if there are multiple root elements I get a warning for each closing tag.

I don't understand what this rule complains as, according its [documentation](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/comment-directive.html), it is there for the eslint-disable comments, which I don't have in my templates.

Comment: Ho @Thomas, where you able to figure this out? I am getting this now after adding a yarn plugin. I tried to remove the plugin and re-install the project, but the error is still there. I find surprisingly very few issues about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue but in nuxt with eslint, i just needed to update eslint-config and eslint-module:

```
"@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^5.0.0",
"@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.1",
```

source: https://github.com/nuxt/eslint-plugin-nuxt/issues/121

Comment: Remember to also upgrade eslint to `^7.22.0` otherwise you might face errors

Answer (score 9):

I've just updated my npm dependencies and I have the same error.

I was reading the eslint documentation and finally I've realized that you can remove the `false error` if you setup the rule in the `.eslintrc.js` config file.

this is my `.eslintrc.js` config file:

```json
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/vue',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended'
  ],
  plugins: [
    'prettier'
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    "vue/comment-directive": 0
  }
}
```

add the rule `"vue/comment-directive": 0` and that is!, the error message is removed!.

the possible values are:

- 0 means `disabled`
- 1 means `warning`
- 2 means `error`

Try to change it in your IDE to how it works

(In my case I've had to stop the server and re-run it every time that I've changed a value in this config file.)

Comment: but why does it happen? You just supressed this error.

Comment: why? eslintrc works in this way. You can see it the eslint documentation...

Comment: Linters tend to drive me crazy. I did the same and disabled the error to be able to continue working but like @AlexanderKim, I'm curious to understand this error as it wasn't there before.

Comment: This is kind of a temporary fix. Because I don't really want to disable `vue/comment-directive`. I'm using eslint-disable comments in my templates...

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error.
I was taught how to fix this error.
https://qiita.com/tashinoso/items/a72741ca8e2fd928ca77#comment-3e6cd674353056ecbb3a

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["*.vue"],
      processor: "vue/.vue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: was using nuxt and typescript. This works.

Comment: would be nice if the link language was in english :/

Answer (score 0):

Set this snippet on .eslintrc.js

```
"vue/comment-directive": ["error", {
  "reportUnusedDisableDirectives": false
  }]
```

Solve my issue, i wonder why. Solution from [documentation](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/comment-directive.html)

Node v12.20.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of a temporary fix that worked for me and I think it will work for you as well.

vue/comment-directive

This rule is included in all of "plugin:vue/base", "plugin:vue/essential", "plugin:vue/vue3-essential", "plugin:vue/strongly-recommended", "plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended", "plugin:vue/recommended" and "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended".

ESLint doesn't provide any API to enhance eslint-disable functionality and ESLint rules cannot affect other rules. But ESLint provides processors API.

This rule sends all eslint-disable-like comments as errors to the post-process of the .vue file processor, then the post-process removes all vue/comment-directive errors and the reported errors in disabled areas.

All you need to do is add
**eslint-disable-next-line vue/component-tags-order**
this line as comment above anywhere you using comments within tags in each block you need to specify if comments are added.

For more information please visit:- https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/comment-directive.html