# Error with eslint and vue/comment directive

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint

Hello I was just running my website and I have 20 errors like this :

```js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js): 
error  clear  vue/comment-directive
```

Any idea what is the problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESLint Vue plugin showing false positives for vue/comment-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529114/eslint-vue-plugin-showing-false-positives-for-vue-comment-directive)

Comment: This helped https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1355

Comment: Where do you have the error? Could you please show us the code? Also, this happened without any action from your part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules that allow eslint to use eslint-disable functionality in the 'template' are  included in all eslint plugin.It supports usage of the following comments:

- eslint-disable
- eslint-enable
- eslint-disable-line
- eslint-disable-next-line

The error you are getting can be solved if you can turn off the vue/comment-directive of the default rules by adding a custom rule in the ***.eslintrc.js*** file

---

```
 rules: {
    'nuxt/no-cjs-in-config': 'off',
    'vue/comment-directive': 'off'
  }
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I had done after, https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1355 thank you